A specific Wi-Fi network randomly disconnect from several laptops in my organization
My organization have a number of ThinkPad Laptops running windows 10 Pro with Intel / Realtek Wi-Fi cards, these connect to a specific WLAN network that is connecting to a number of specific critical services provided by another organization and is not allowed to route to outside networks like google.com or Microsoft.
Problem is that this connection randomly disconnects for unknown reasons. this problem doesn't happen with any other WLAN Connection broadcasted from our ARUBA access points. I don't know how to stop or even troubleshoot this issue as it is random and have no access for the services they use. What things should I check for on either the laptop or the access point configurations?

Does this happen on ALL the ThinkPad laptops, on ALL of a specific model or generation of laptop, or just a random subset of laptops? Right now you should be looking at the logs you CAN see, so those of the laptops, and of the Aruba controller. It is less like the issue is due to the services being offered over the WLAN, so don't worry about that at this point. Look for things that are the same between the different laptops impacts, and different between those laptops and the ones not impacted: driver versions, OS versions, patch levels, running software, etc.

They happen on Thinkpad laptops, which all the same model, and another set of older laptops that are HP, Problem with logs is that I don't know how to look at PC for the logs and when as it happens randomly. as for Aruba controller, I'm not the one who has acesss over it but even though i don't know what to look for there. this doesn't happen on other provided WLANs from the same access points. it's narrowed down to either a problem with windows or a problem with that specific SSID configuration.
